# Google Cloud SDK version mismatch

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have 2 computers same OS/google-cloud-sdk versions. What's the reason to have version mismatch in some of components?

Installed following [Quickstart for Linux](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-linux)

```
[term@localhost ~]$ gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 295.0.0
alpha 2019.05.17
beta 2019.05.17
bq 2.0.57
core 2020.05.29
gsutil 4.51
kubectl 2020.05.01
```

Installed following [Quickstart for Red Hat and Centos](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-redhat-centos)

```
[term2@localhost]$ gcloud version 
Google Cloud SDK 295.0.0
alpha 2020.05.29
beta 2020.05.29
bq 2.0.57
core 2020.05.29
gsutil 4.51
kubectl 2020.05.29
```

Why alpha, beta, kubectl have a mismatch? if I do `gcloud components update` to match 2020.05.29 I get:

`All components are up to date.`

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud SDK components version vary because you have 2 different sources

In `term2` you are using a repository to get the new packages, this way your installation is less likely to miss an update and always offers the latest version for distribution.

But in `term` you are using manual installation, a good way to fix it is uninstalling the old SDK on `term` and re-install it by using the latest `.tar.gz`

To uninstall your gcloud old version, please remove the folder installation, to get the installation folder please execute the following command:

```
which gcloud
```

To reinstall a new version

1. Download the Linux 64-bit archive file from your command-line, run:

```
curl -O https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-296.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
```

2. Extract the archive to any location on your file system; preferably, your Home folder. On Linux, you can extract the archive file by running this command:

```
tar zxvf [ARCHIVE_FILE] google-cloud-sdk
```

3. Run the installation script

```
./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you faced some temporary issue.

I've checked on my test project and found no version mismatch:

1. Create VM instances based on CentOS 8:

```
$ gcloud compute instances create instance-1 --zone=europe-west3-a --machine-type=e2-medium --image=centos-8-v20200910 --image-project=centos-cloudCreated 
$ gcloud compute instances create instance-2 --zone=europe-west3-a --machine-type=e2-medium --image=centos-8-v20200910 --image-project=centos-cloud
```

2. Manually install Google Cloud SDK:

```
$ gcloud compute ssh instance-1
instance-1 ~]$ sudo yum update
instance-1 ~]$ curl -O https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-313.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
instance-1 ~]$ tar xvfz google-cloud-sdk-313.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
instance-1 ~]$ ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
```

3. Install Google Cloud SDK from packages:

```
$ gcloud compute ssh instance-2
instance-2 ~]$ sudo yum update
instance-2 ~]$ sudo tee -a /etc/yum.repos.d/google-cloud-sdk.repo << EOM
> [google-cloud-sdk]
> name=Google Cloud SDK
> baseurl=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/cloud-sdk-el7-x86_64
> enabled=1
> gpgcheck=1
> repo_gpgcheck=1
> gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg
>        https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
> EOM
```

4. Check versions:

```
instance-1 ~]$ gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 313.0.0
alpha 2020.10.02
beta 2020.10.02
bq 2.0.61
core 2020.10.02
gsutil 4.53
kubectl 1.15.11
```

and

```
instance-2 ~]$ gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 313.0.0
alpha 2020.10.02
beta 2020.10.02
bq 2.0.61
core 2020.10.02
gsutil 4.53
kubectl 1.15.11
```

also at Debian 10:

```
$ gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 313.0.0
alpha 2020.10.02
beta 2020.10.02
bq 2.0.61
core 2020.10.02
gsutil 4.53
kubectl 1.15.11
```

in addition, I've updated packages at Google Shell to get Google Cloud SDK 313.0.0 and found same versions of components.

It's better to install Google Cloud SDK from packages to have them updated with other software.

**If you found version mismatch again** you can file an [issue report](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#issue_reports) at [Google Cloud Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).